# Pivot table based on SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel

I have a pivot table that is tracking our billing payups and calculating profit/loss. The pivot table is pulled from a SQL query currently. It has been requested that the expense column be figured by the number of pieces mailed * 0.78. This is easy enough but the problem comes in because they want to be able to change the 0.78 to the proper amount as time goes by. Is there anyway to get the SQL query to look at a field in Excel where they can change the amount to what is needed. I originally set it up as a calculated field so they could just edit that formula but they are just wanting to be able to update this with an excel field from sheet2.

Comment: you can define formulas in Pivot tables!

Answer (score 0):

What I would probably suggest doing is have the 0.78 value stored in the database, and export that to Excel.  I don't use Excel much these days, but I believe there is a way to set it up so that when the field changes in Excel and you save it, it will get updated in the database as well (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Then just have your select query pull the field from the same place, and use it as the multiplier.

Comment: I am attempting to do this through a macro but how would I assign the Excel cell that I want to use. For example, I want to update SQL table opi_bill_cost with the value from Sheet3.B2. This is my first attempt at using VBA so please bear with me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.